# Change ajax UpdatetargetID depends of model state validation MVC

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

Lets say i've got simple ajax begin form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DodajTresc", "Administracja", new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Czy jesteś pewien że chcesz dodać treść ?", InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "podgladDodanejTresc", LoadingElementId = "spinWiadomosci" }))
{
    some code[...]
}
```

Is it possible to change UpdatetargetID after post depends of model state validation ?. For exmaple:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    UpdatetargetID="div1";
}
else
{
    UpdatetargetID="div2";
}
```

Is there an option to achieved that ?

Comment: you can use onError and if State not valid throw exception and do whatever is needed in onError js function

Comment: Ok, I will try with that. Thanks !